# server validate RadComboBox with Load on demand with Custom text is true

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How can I validate RadComboBox on the server side with LoadonDemand true and AllowCustomText is true? I have the following code but it doesn't validate correctly.

```
  protected void RadComboBox1ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs arg)
    {
        arg.IsValid = RadComboBox1.SelectedValue.Length > 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the selected text or value of the combobox instead of its selectedvalue when using LOD.

Answer (score 0):

In `Combobox_SelectedIndexChange` event, check RadComboBox if there is selectedValue > 0.  If selected value > 0, then you must think that the custom text entered.